# Advise on implementing multiple check boxes into an excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, phpexcel, vba

My team is implementing real estate data into our excel (CSV) template, then implementing that data into our platform. One Field requires multiple property type selections be entered in and separated by comma. We want to replace the writing and commas with a box of selections that can then be checked. I am not a programmer; my programmers are slammed and I am trying to help them out. Any advice is greatly appreciated. TIA.
~Brendan

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in a CSV, but it can be done in an Excel file.  The basic directions can be found here:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2042382/add-checkboxes-to-an-excel-spreadsheet.html

Basically, you have to enable the Developer tab in Excel (a quick Google search will show you how to do it on your personal version of Excel)

This next language is borrowed directly from Lincoln Spector's article:

"To insert a checkbox, click the Developer tab, then click the Insert icon in the Controls section. From the resulting pop-up menu, select the checkbox icon in the Form Controls section.

The mouse pointer will turn into a plus sign. Click where you want the checkbox to appear. You can drag and drop it elsewhere later.

Now you need to set the checkbox up. Right-click it and select Format Control. You'll find various options here, but these two are particularly important:

Click the Control tab, go to the Cell link field, and enter a cell address (or click the icon to the right and select one). The contents of that cell will change when the checkbox is checked or unchecked, displaying either True or False, and thus allowing you to create formulas that react to the checkbox's status."

After this is done, you would make a formula.  So, let's pretend you have your true/false values in A2-C2, and that you want to print various kinds of text based on these values.  You would use a formula like:

`=IF(A2=true,"purchased","not purchased")&","&IF(B2=true,"repaired","needs repair")&","&IF(C2=true,"someOtherValue","whatever you need here")`

The `&","&` bits just add comma separators. `&` concatenates two bits of text together.